# Data Get in Json using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 3 column 26 path $[0].data

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Api_Interface api_interface;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        api_interface=ApiClient.getClient().create(Api_Interface.class);

        Call<List<CountryClas>> call=api_interface.getcountry("GetCountry","727","cl1oEntQ32PxZsS3VJnC+H+CY5oLfFLRU5j1H4bg+1g=");




      call.enqueue(new Callback<List<CountryClas>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<CountryClas>> call, Response<List<CountryClas>> response) {
                Log.e("Res",">>>>>>"+response.body());
                }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<CountryClas>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Error",">>>>>>"+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**InterFace**

```
public interface Api_Interface {

@GET("json.php")
Call<List<CountryClas>> getcountry(@Query("action") String action, @Query("umID") String umID
        , @Query("OauthToken") String OauthToken);

}
```

**ApiClient**

```
public class ApiClient {
    private static final String BaseUrl="http://23.227.133.210/consultapro/";

    private static Retrofit retrofit=null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(){
        if (retrofit==null){
            retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**Model Class**

```
public class CountryClas {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private Boolean status;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Datum> data = null;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    public Boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<Datum> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

**Second Model Class**

```
public class Datum {

    @SerializedName("Country_Id")
    @Expose
    private String countryId;
    @SerializedName("Country_Name")
    @Expose
    private String countryName;
    @SerializedName("Country_Code")
    @Expose
    private String countryCode;

    public String getCountryId() {
        return countryId;
    }

    public void setCountryId(String countryId) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

}
```

//Json Response

[
    {
        "status": true,
        "data": [
            {
                "Country_Id": "101",
                "Country_Name": "India",
                "Country_Code": "91"
            },
            {
                "Country_Id": "231",
                "Country_Name": "United States",
                "Country_Code": "1"
            },
            {
                "Country_Id": "230",
                "Country_Name": "United Kingdom",
                "Country_Code": "44"
            }
      ],
        "message": "Country list found."
    }
]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gson: Expected begin\_array but was STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795614/gson-expected-begin-array-but-was-string)

Comment: it's an issue from your model class , please recheck your datatype

Comment: Please share your json response string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//There are some issue to define in InterFace here is code

public interface Api_Interface {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("json.php")
    Call<List<CountryClas>> getcountry(@Field("action") String action, @Field("umID") String umID
        , @Field("OauthToken") String OauthToken);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

'Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING' means your member variable which you have define their datatype is not matching, it's expecting as **String[]** might be, and you may have used **Sting** , please recheck.

Answer (score 0):

That means your Json data model is wrong. Just use some online json to Java model converter to generate model if you dont know what is wrong.

try this [converter](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

This model should actually work if you posted right Json string

```
class Country {
@SerializedName("status")
private Boolean status;

@SerializedName("data")
private List<Data> data = null;

@SerializedName("message")
private String message;

public class Data {
    @SerializedName("Country_Id")
    private String countryId;

    @SerializedName("Country_Name")
    private String countryName;

    @SerializedName("Country_Code")
    private String countryCode;
}}
```

Comment: please post your json string

Comment: [{"status":true,"data":[{"Country_Id":"101","Country_Name":"India","Country_Code":"91"},{"Country_Id":"231","Country_Name":"United States","Country_Code":"1"},{"Country_Id":"230","Country_Name":"United Kingdom","Country_Code":"44"},{"Country_Id":"1","Country_Name":"Afghanistan","Country_Code":"93"},{"Country_Id":"2","Country_Name":"Albania","Country_Code":"355"} ],
        "message": "Country list found."
    }
]

Answer (score 0):

I try to connect your api without authentication

`http://23.227.133.210/consultapro/json.php?action=getCountry`,

then I get the response like this

`[{"status":false,"data":"-->getCountry-->3JfalKdsUf15fsfGIwjcXg== -->","message":"User is not authenticated."}]`

in data, it return String instead of ARRAY

So I think because you request with an **invalid authentication** It will make your model is incorrect -> JsonParseException

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: http://23.227.133.210/consultapro/json.php?action=getCountry&umID=727&OauthToken=cl1oEntQ32PxZsS3VJnC+H+CY5oLfFLRU5j1H4bg+1g= -> Authentication error

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your response body to Java Objects/List using Gson. See code sample below

```
req.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            BufferedReader reader = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.body().byteStream()));
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String result = sb.toString();

            ApiResponse apiResponse = new Gson().fromJson(result, ApiResponse.class);
```