# Why am I getting a JsonSyntaxException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING here?

Tags: java, android, json, exception, gson

I have one JSON file:

```
{
"settings": {
    "header": {
        "id": "240A64CDC43F",
        "filename": "network",
        "sequence": "0",
        "last_modified": "2015-04-21T16:33",
        "JSON_file_version": "2.1"
    },
    "data": {
        "engine_config": {
            "bed_name": "IdealTempCDC43F",
            "provisioned": "false",
            "connected": "false",
            "IP_address": "192.168.10.1",
            "connection_error": "None"
        },
        "networks": {
            "available": "7",
            "SSIDs": {
                "wireless_1": {
                    "SSID": "$$ASI_WIFI$$",
                    "mac_address": "A0:EC:F9:11:35:04",
                    "channel": "11",
                    "RSSI": "-64dBm",
                    "security": "true",
                    "security_type": "WPA"
                },
                "wireless_2": {
                    "SSID": "$$ASI_GUEST$$",
                    "mac_address": "A0:EC:F9:11:35:02",
                    "channel": "11",
                    "RSSI": "-65dBm",
                    "security": "true",
                    "security_type": "WPA"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

For parsing this json I am using this:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request); 
String strResponse = response.toString();
parseJSON(strResponse);
```

and

```
public void parseJSON(String jsonString) {
  Gson gsonParser = new Gson();
  ProveQuerySetting gsonResponse = new ProveQuerySetting();
  Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<ProveQuerySetting>>() {
  }.getType();
  gsonResponse = gsonParser.fromJson(jsonString, collectionType);
  String str = gsonParser.toJson(gsonResponse);
  System.out.println(" final json " + str);
}
```

But I am getting this exception:

```
04-21 07:08:13.864: W/System.err(4187): com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
04-21 07:08:13.864: W/System.err(4187): com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
04-21 07:08:13.865: W/System.err(4187):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:822)
04-21 07:08:13.865: W/System.err(4187):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
04-21 07:08:13.865: W/System.err(4187):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
04-21 07:08:13.865: W/System.err(4187):     at com.easi.main.network.NetworkCom.parseJSON(NetworkCom.java:127)
04-21 07:08:13.865: W/System.err(4187):     at com.easi.main.network.NetworkCom.sendFirst(NetworkCom.java:50)
04-21 07:08:13.865: W/System.err(4187):     at com.easi.main.setting.ConnectToBox$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(ConnectToBox.java:89)
04-21 07:08:13.865: W/System.err(4187):     at com.easi.main.setting.ConnectToBox$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(ConnectToBox.java:1)
04-21 07:08:13.865: W/System.err(4187):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-21 07:08:13.865: W/System.err(4187):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-21 07:08:13.865: W/System.err(4187):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-21 07:08:13.865: W/System.err(4187):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-21 07:08:13.865: W/System.err(4187):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-21 07:08:13.865: W/System.err(4187):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-21 07:08:13.865: W/System.err(4187): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
04-21 07:08:13.865: W/System.err(4187):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
04-21 07:08:13.866: W/System.err(4187):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:79)
04-21 07:08:13.866: W/System.err(4187):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
04-21 07:08:13.866: W/System.err(4187):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
04-21 07:08:13.866: W/System.err(4187):     ... 12 more
```

Here is my POJO class:

```
public class ProveQuerySetting {
  ProvQueryData provEngnData;
  ProvQueryHeader provEngnhHeader;

  public ProvQueryData getProvEngnData() {
    return provEngnData;
  }

  public void setProvEngnData(ProvQueryData provEngnData) {
    this.provEngnData = provEngnData;
  }

  public ProvQueryHeader getProvEngnhHeader() {
    return provEngnhHeader;
  }

  public void setProvEngnhHeader(ProvQueryHeader provEngnhHeader) {
    this.provEngnhHeader = provEngnhHeader;
  }
}
```

Why I am getting this exception?

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ - not a valid json

Comment: This is valid json.Working for iOS

Comment: I take you JSON you posted, and valiidadted with http://jsonlint.com/ . JSON Is not correct in `Parse error on line 1:
{    settings: {        
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'`

Comment: @BlueGreen  http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ - 2 sites independetly are saying it's not valid json. iOS may have error handling that can work with it, but it's not valid json

Comment: @BlueGreen do you get the same error with this edited json?

Comment: @BlueGreen takee a look at this : [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566644/com-google-gson-jsonsyntaxexception-expected-begin-array-but-was-string) seems like your class is expecting `settings` to be array, but it's getting just objects instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so you are trying to use the default Gson. Great! The default Gson is smart, but not that smart. You have to design your classes to **exactly match** the format of the json you're getting back, or use the [`@SerializedName`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation, if you don't want to design a custom deserializer. When I say **exactly match**, I mean, the field names must be **exactly the same** as the serialized Gson, either in the field name or the annotation.

I created the following POJOs (including yours, with modified field names). I have not included the getters/setters for brevity:

```
public class ProvEngineConfig {
  private String bed_name;
  private String provisioned;
  private String connected;
  private String IP_Address;
  private String connection_error;
}

public class ProvNetworks {
  private String available;
  private Map<String, ProvSSID> SSIDs;  // Notice this is a map
}

public class ProveQuerySetting {
  ProvQueryData data;
  ProvQueryHeader header;
}

public class ProvQueryData {
  ProvEngineConfig engine_config;
  ProvNetworks networks;
}

public class ProvQueryHeader {
  String id;
  String filename;
  String sequence;
  String last_modified;
  String JSON_file_version;
}

public class ProvSSID {
  String SSID;
  String mac_address;
  String channel;
  String RSSI;
  String security;
  String security_type;
}
```

Again, do you see how the field names are **exactly** the same as the ones in your JSON? Notice that in `ProvNetworks`, I'm using a map, because the JSON you provided is a map of wireless names to exactly matching SSID objects.

Once my POJOs were set up like the following, notice also that your provided JSON is not a `Collection` of Query settings, it's actually a `Map<String, ProvQuerySetting>`, you map from the word `"settings"` to the Engine config object. So I parsed it like this:

```
public static void parseJSON(String jsonString) {
  Gson gsonParser = new Gson();
  Map<String, ProveQuerySetting> gsonResponse; // You don't need to do new here
  Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Map<String, ProveQuerySetting>>() {}.getType();
  gsonResponse = gsonParser.fromJson(jsonString, collectionType);

  String str = gsonParser.toJson(gsonResponse);
  System.out.println(" final json " + str);
}
```

Output:

```
final json {"settings":{"data":{"engine_config":{"bed_name":"IdealTempCDC43F","provisioned":"false","connected":"false","connection_error":"None"},"networks":{"available":"7","SSIDs":{"wireless_1":{"SSID":"$$ASI_WIFI$$","mac_address":"A0:EC:F9:11:35:04","channel":"11","RSSI":"-64dBm","security":"true","security_type":"WPA"},"wireless_2":{"SSID":"$$ASI_GUEST$$","mac_address":"A0:EC:F9:11:35:02","channel":"11","RSSI":"-65dBm","security":"true","security_type":"WPA"}}}},"header":{"id":"240A64CDC43F","filename":"network","sequence":"0","last_modified":"2015-04-21T16:33","JSON_file_version":"2.1"}}}
```

---

### To summarize:

You either need to:

1. **Exactly** match your POJOs and field names/annotated field names to match the JSON
2. Write your own custom deserializer, as described in [`JsonReader`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1298/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html)

Comment: _"I mean, the field names must be exactly the same as the serialized Gson."_ Not necessarily, you can use the annotation `@SerializedName` if you want to stick with the java coding conventions. For example: `@SerializedName("json_name") private datatype javaName;`

Comment: No Doubt... Your suggestion helped a lot. I really appreciate you effort.

Comment: I need one more small help, How to get data from "collectionType". A small hint will be sufficient.

Comment: @durron597..Now data get parsed successfully. How i will used parsed data for view in my project

Answer (score 0):

Gson API is good but i found one more API [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) more robust and user friendly. Need two jar files jackson-core-asl-1.8.5 and jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.5
and then

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MAinpojo object = null;
    System.out.println("json string  "+jsonString.trim());
    try {
         object = mapper.readValue(new URL("http://192.168.xx.x/pmmm-zzzz"), MAinpojo.class);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And last but not least be care full about your POJO classes.

1.Field name should be same.

2.If getting **Unrecognized exception** at some field then use Annotation like this

```
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class MAinpojo {

     @JsonProperty("settings") 
     ProveQuerySetting settings;


     @JsonProperty("settings") 
     public ProveQuerySetting getSettings() {
        return settings;
    }

    public void setSettings(ProveQuerySetting settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

}
```

Above all fields, where the  possibility to throw exception.